# How to shutdown gracefully in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, mysql-connector, sveltekit

I am using adapter-node and a mysql pool in a sveltekit web app.

Previously, using just nodejs and express and no sveltekit, I found I needed to shutdown the mysql pool connections cleanly or mysql could hang when restarting the app.

I had something like:

```js
  process.on('SIGINT', () => server.close(() => pool.end()));
```

How would I achieve the same result in a sveltekit app? Or is it not necessary (and why)?

I can see in the sveltekit implementation where it creates the server, but does not seem to have any way to access it so I can call close(). I don't think it would be safe to call pool.end() before the server closes.

I also couldn't find any discussion of graceful shutdown in the sveltekit docs. There was 1 github issue but it was closed over a year ago and that change has since been removed from the code.

I found a similar issue asked in the svelte github. It has no resolution, so there is likely no official solution yet. https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/6841

Comment: I thought the answer was to use a custom server as documented in the adapter-node README. But it does not give enough information on how to set that up. So I don't know anymore.

Comment: What information are you missing?

Comment: It doesn't describe how to hook your custom server into the adapter. After more investigation, I think the docs are out of date. The implementation used to have an option called entryPoint, but that was removed.

Comment: The next thing I tried was making a custom adapter, by copying adapter node and changing the index.js to what I wanted. But ultimately that doesn't work because I couldn't figure out how to access the variables outside the adapter. Or if I create the database pool inside the adapter, I couldn't figure out how to access the pool from svelte code.

Comment: For now, I think the answer is that SvelteKit is still in early days, pre-1.0, and prioritizes the serverless case. So keeping the adapter and rest of the app separate is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimers at the time of writing this answer:

- I am brand new to Svelte and SvelteKit and only a couple years into web development in general
- SvelteKit is pre-1.0 and subject to change
- I am not 100% sure this answer handles all cases
- I am using `adapter-node`

SvelteKit currently recommends doing one-time setup code in `src/hooks.server.ts`. So when talking about graceful shutdown, I will only worry about shutting down the things I setup in `src/hooks.server.ts`.

The brief answer is to set up `process.on()` handlers for `exit` and `SIGINT` that do any required cleanup.

An example for setting up and shutting down a mysql database pool when using `adapter-node`:

```js
// src/hooks.server.ts

// One time setup code
await import('./db.js');

// ... remaining hooks.server.ts code
```

```js
// src/db.ts

import { PRIVATE_MYSQL_PASSWORD } from '$env/static/private';
import type { Pool, PoolConnection, MysqlError } from 'mysql';
import { createPool } from 'mysql';

const pool = createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: PRIVATE_MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  database: 'my_db',
  multipleStatements: false,
  timezone: 'UTC',
  dateStrings: ['DATE', 'DATETIME'],
});

process.on('exit', (code) => end_db_pool(pool));
process.on('SIGINT', () => end_db_pool(pool));

function end_db_pool(pool: any) {
  pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query('select 1 from my_table;', function (err, rows) {
      connection.release();
      // pool.end() only works inside getConnection();
      pool.end((err) => {
        if (err) log('pool.end err: ' + err);
      });
    });
  });
}

// ... remaining API for DB operations using the pool
```

Another solution I tried and might still be useful is to create a custom adapter. I copied the `adapter-node` code into my project and modified `files/index.js` for some experimenting. For now, I am using the code above and not a custom `adapter-node`.

Comment: Is this method still working? I need to check the `.env` file using zod and I need to do that before the application starts receiving request. I tried to put a simple `console.log` in `src/hooks.server.ts` but it doesn't execute until the first request.

Comment: I switched from sveltekit to svelte-spa-router. Sorry, I don't know if this still works. 

One idea is to search the sveltekit github issues. I found that is where I often learned the best way to use sveltekit.